# Getting the list of zones in Google Cloud Compute using Java SDK

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google Cloud Platform and have been scouring their docs to find how to get a list of all the Zones. 
There are very few examples or Getting Started Pages. Their documentation clearly is of little value.

How do I get the list of Zones using the Java SDK?

Comment: Are you asking about this? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/viewing-regions-zones

Comment: `Compute.zones()` (https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/compute/Compute.html#zones--) sounds promising.